# Find a decomposition of vector space as direct sum of five modules

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and $h : V \rightarrow V$ a linear map. For $p \in \mathbb{F}[X]$ and $v \in V$ we define a multiplication $p \cdot v = p(h)(v)$. 
Now let's say $$h(v) = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}v.$$

Find a decomposition of $V$ as direct sum of five $\mathbb{F}[X]$ modules, that can be generated by a single vector and explicitly specify these vectors.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see some feature of that matrix which breaks it into $5$ parts?

Comment: The matrix has 5 eigenvectors, so I guess their eigenspaces?

Comment: It only has three distinct eigenvalues, but you are on the right track.

Comment: The matrix also has 5 Jordan blocks but I have no idea how they help me creating $\mathbb{F}[X]$ submodules.

Comment: The Jordan blocks are indeed where I was going. Are you familiar with generalized eigenvectors?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm afraid

Comment: Ok. What you should do is look at what happens when you apply the matrix to various standard basis vectors.

Comment: If I multiply the matrix with the standard basis vectors, the result are the columns of the matrix ([calculated here](https://i.imgur.com/rBp89vX.png)). What does that tell me?

Comment: For each of them, write up which of the standard basis vectors are needed to write the result.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. The result should be V, a 9 dimensional vector space, but I may pick only 5 single vectors. They're linear independent, so I can pick them randomly, but the result will always be 5-dimensional. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The subspaces will not be 1-dimensional. They should be generated by a single vector *as $\mathbb{F}[x]$-modules*.

Comment: Can you elaborate how a generating vector of the module can generate a subspace with a dimension greater than 1? Also, how can I ever find such a polynomial?

Comment: The vector generates everything you can get by multiplying it by powers of the given matrix, as well as linear combinations of these. So for example the second standard basis vector generates the subspace spanned by the first two standard basis vectors.

Comment: So would the standard basis vectors $e_7$, $e_2$, $e_4 + e_6$, $e_5$, $e_9$ a solution to the question ([see here](https://i.imgur.com/7sI1iuZ.png))? $e_7$ generates only one vector of the subspace but for the other ones $h(e_i)$ generates one that is linearly independent from $e_i$. All of them combined are linearly independent.
Does that suffice?

Comment: I am not sure where the $e_4+e_6$ came from. $e_6$ is an eigenvector, so it will form one of these spaces by itself (together with scalar multiples). Instead of $e_4$, you should have $e_5$, which gives you $e_4$ by multiplying with the matrix once (and taking linear combinations), and then you get $e_3$ by multiplying once more.